# How to replace empty value with value from another row

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with a dataframe that has some empty cells. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'id2': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'color': ["red", "", "green", "yellow", "", "blue"], 'rate':["good","","good","average","","good"]})

    id  id2 color   rate
0   1   1   red     good
1   2   1       
2   3   1   green   good
3   1   2   yellow  average
4   2   2       
5   3   2   blue    good
```

For both the columns "color" and "rate", I would like to replace the empty rows with values from another row where id is 1. Therefore, I would like the dataframe to look like this in the end:

```
    id  id2 color   rate
0   1   1   red     good
1   2   1   red     good    
2   3   1   green   good
3   1   2   yellow  average
4   2   2   yellow  average 
5   3   2   blue    good
```

I prefer not to replace the empty cells with values from the previous row. I would like to indicate the id and replace the empty cells with rows that have the specific id.

Comment: There are two rows with `id == 1`, so which row should replace the empty values?

Comment: Yes. It looks for the same value in column "id2".

Answer (score 0):

Its only works if the number of rows with empty values in [color,rate] is equal to the number of rows with id==1. Expand further on the question of whether this is not the intention.
If I understood you correctly:

```
empty_rows = df.loc[df['color']=='',['color','rate']].index
df.loc[empty_rows, ['color','rate']] = df.loc[df['id']==1,['color','rate']].values
```

Result df:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can `groupby` and `transform` with `first`, and finally assign to empty values:

```
df.loc[df["color"].eq(""), ["color", "rate"]] = df.groupby(df["id"].eq(1).cumsum())[["color","rate"]].transform("first")

print (df)

   id  id2   color     rate
0   1    1     red     good
1   2    1     red     good
2   3    1   green     good
3   1    2  yellow  average
4   2    2  yellow  average
5   3    2    blue     good
```